# How to append an AJAX reply

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched the site and surprisingly did not find any answers fitting my situation. So I posted this question.

I am using jQuery AJAX to fetch a web page and dynamically add it to the website. But my code does not work and throws an error `ERROR TypeError: "data.append is not a function"`.

My code is:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:3000/treeviewuser/testuser",
      beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
      }
    })
      .done(function( data ) {
        if ( console && console.log ) {
          console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
          data.append(data);
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: `data` is the response returned from the endpoint. What are you trying to do?

Comment: To add the response to the document

Comment: Then you need to write it to a pre-existing element, or create an element and then append it to the document. Your code doesn't really make much sense even if it is syntactically correct: why are you appending data to itself?

Comment: I changed it to  `$("div").append(data);` and now it spams the whole page with multiple responses..

Comment: @Munchkin Because then you're appending the data to **all `<div>` elements on the page**, which you don't want.

Comment: ohh, right, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To further elabourate on my comment, `data` is the response returned from the endpoint, which does not have the `.append()` method. Based on your response, you intend to print the output to the document. There are two ways to do this:

### 1. Create a new element with the text, and append to document

If you do not have a target element on the page you want to append the data to, you can simply create a new element and set its inner text to the data returned from the server:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/treeviewuser/testuser",
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
    }
}).done(function( data ) {
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerText = data;

    document.appendChild(el);
});
```

If you're more comfortable writing in jQuery, you can also do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/treeviewuser/testuser",
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
    }
}).done(function( data ) {
    const $el = $('<div />', {
        text: data
    });

    $(document).append($el);
});
```

### 2. Append text to a pre-existing element

Let's say you have an element with the ID of `output` that you want to print the response to, i.e. `<div id="output"></div>`, then you can do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/treeviewuser/testuser",
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
    }
}).done(function( data ) {
    $('#output').text(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the element where you want to append the response data.
`$("#my_div_id").append(data[0])` instead of  `data.append(data);`
If your data is an ***`array`*** or an ***`array of objects`***, you'll need to loop through each of them when appending; else when the data you return from your ajax is in a type of ***`text`*** or ***`html`***, you can just directly append it on your document. `$("#my_div_id").append(data)`